# I need deep copy of C#.NET Array

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an integer Array of 5 elements which is filled with dummy data. The question is how can I create a deep copy of this array.I am working in c#.net
Suppose I have int[] Array1 = new int[5];

Thanks in advance

Comment: A "deep" copy of an array of ints is meaningless.  Just use `Array.Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone() is good enough. refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054075/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-array-in-c) for more information.