# Unity C# Array - how to clone

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Im developing a small app/game in Unity3D.

The problem is: 
I need to clone an array (call it tempArray) and make some modifications to it. Then i need to change values of the MAIN array to modified tempArray. However, whenever i make changes to cloned array, the same changes are made to the main one.

So i used the following code:

```
private Cell[,] allCells = new Cell[256, 256];
private Cell[,] cellClone = new Cell[256,256];

//meanwhile initiated to some values//

//Here i clone the array.
cellClone = (Cell[,])allCells.Clone();

//Here i output the values for an element from both arrays.
Debug.Log(cellClone[0, 0].region.name.ToString());
Debug.Log(allCells[0, 0].region.name.ToString());

//Here i want to change "Region" variable of cellClone ONLY.
cellClone[0, 0].setRegion(new Region("testregion123", Color.cyan, false));

//Finally, i output the same values again. Only cellClone should change.
Debug.Log(cellClone[0, 0].region.name.ToString());
Debug.Log(allCells[0, 0].region.name.ToString());
```

However, the output shows that allCells[0,0] element was also changed. This means that any operation I do to the cloned array, is executed to the main array.

---

EDIT:

After alot of playing around I implemented this as a solution. Im posting this in case anybody has a similar problem.

But Im not sure if this is how its supposed to be done so if anybody has any information - Ill be checking this post.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCells.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < allCells.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        //cellClone[i, j] = allCells[i, j].Clone();
        //cellClone[i, j] = new Cell((int)allCells[i, j].position.x, (int)allCells[i, j].position.y, allCells[i, j].getRegionName());
        cellClone[i, j] = allCells[i, j].clone();
    }
}
```

And the clone function:

```
public Cell clone()
{
        Cell n = new Cell((int)position.x, (int)position.y, regionName);
        return n;
}
```

Comment: have you checked out `Deep Copy or Clone.? here is some example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054075/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: I tried the deep copy. However, i dropped it when it asked me to set "UnityEngine.Vector2" as serializable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the output shows that allCells[0,0] element was also changed. This means that any operation I do to the cloned array, is executed to the main array.

Unless `Cell` is a struct, your `setRegion` method (which sounds like it should really just be a `Region` property) isn't changing the contents of the array at all. It's changing the data stored in the object that both arrays contain a *reference* to.

You're performing a *shallow clone* of the array, which means the references are being copied - but each `Cell` object is *not* being cloned. (We don't even know whether that operation has been implemented within `Cell`.)

It sounds like you want to perform a deep clone, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCells.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < allCells.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
         cellClone[i, j] = allCells[i, j].Clone();
    }
}
```

... where you'd need to implement the `Clone` method yourself. (It may need to clone the region in turn, for example.)

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Array.Copy (Array, Array, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Easier and only 1 line of code;

Comment: This is the best answer, I don't see why Jon Skeet answer is on top